# Can we write LaTeX inside python turtle graphics?

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to write latex inside a figure drawn with turtle graphics. It doesn't accept it in the turtle.write() command. Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Neither Python nor `turtle` have any knowledge of LaTeX. As workaround:

1. Write a LaTeX file (e.g. with class `standalone`) from Python with the desired LaTeX text.
2. Compile (`subprocess`) the LaTeX file to an image format that is supported by `turtle` (probably a bitmap format).
3. Include the generated image in `turtle`.